# Conditional .htaccess rule for multisite sitemap.xml

Tags: 7, multi-sites, .htaccess

We have multiple sites hosted with Domain access module. I was planning to host sitemap.xml files like web_root/zyx.com/sitemap.xml and web_root/abc.com/sitemap.xml.

I am using the following code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xzy.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ /xzy.com/sitemap.xml
```

This code isn't universal and it requires to duplicate it every time a new domain is added.

How can this code be improved to serve sitemaps from web_root/website_name/sitemap.xml?

Comment: Ignore my previous comments. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158649/htaccess-get-domain-name-from-http-host-into-variable-minus-the-www

Comment: I'd let a Sitemap module generate and manage sitemaps automatically. Then you don't have to edit your .htaccess.